# Get the list of packages used in Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda

Is there a way to get a list of packages that are being **used** rather than just installed in the environment?

Example: I can install `matplotlib` with `conda install matplotlib`, but if I never used it in any of the files I don't want it to be in the list.

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/pip-check-reqs/

Comment: Used by what? You essentially are looking for library to scrap finite number of python modules, and get all the imported classes from them (assuming there are no redundant imports)

Comment: What do you mean by "used" exactly?

Comment: Not sure how else to describe "used" other than the definition of the word. Following on the `matplotlib` example, if none of the files have anything like `from matplotlib import...` it hasn't been used

Comment: @dfundako That's pretty cool. Will that also work for conda packages or just pip installed ones?

Comment: @Penguin I don't know. I just googled "python get packages not in use"

Answer (score 0):

Interesting idea to check the 'frequently used' packages in your environment.
It appears to me that there is no direct way for checking.

I am also attempting to work out this topic now. My layman idea is that we can do it in two consecutive stages: (a) to find out the most-used packages which were either often updated (checked using `conda list --revisions`) or easily recognized by the user; (b) to trace the dependencies of those packages (whether one package related to another package, or not) through `pipdeptree` command for checking packages' dependencies. This Anaconda link might also be useful: [Managing Anaconda packages](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html)

The first step is to identify those most-used packages in your applications from time to time. Then only tracing their dependencies with other packages so that related packages were not unfavorably removed. Despite that, I still think it is better to stick with the default packages provided by Conda and will only add more packages if required.